# Python and Html real time data

Tags: javascript, python, sqlite

I have a python script which is collecting data that look like this:

```
> Total visitor today: 30
> Current visitors:    5
```

And I would like to show that data in a small html site in real time. Is there a way to interact this 2 languages? maybe using a small SQLite DB or simply a .txt? .csv? .xml? how can avoid writing and reading at the same time?

I have some limitation in the environment. I only have 16Mb to use and I can currently use SQLite, html, JavaScript and basic python.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using beautiful soup.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm on it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building a basic [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) webapp. Not only can you dynamically update your webpage without needing a refresh (check out [Flask-Sijax](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Sijax/)), it will also host it for you out of the box, meaning you can save yourself the work getting a full web server installed to your limited storage. Flask is only 550 kB and is BSD licensed!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a python library for xml writing and reading. https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html